# Access query: show the first records

Tags: ms-access

I have a table like this:

```
name1      | name2  | value1
-------------------------
Apple      | asdg   | 100
Apple      | ghf    |  50
Lemon      | dhjhgf |  60
Meat       | iop    | 300
Meat       | pdjs   |  70
Meat       | ncm    |  10
Strawberry | jdksa  |  20
```

What should I do to get this:

```
name1      | name2  | value1
----------------------------
Apple      | asdg   | 100
Lemon      | dhjhgf |  60
Meat       | iop    | 300
Strawberry | jdksa  |  20
```

Comment: What SQL statement have you tried so far?  We dont do work for you, we help guide you down the best path, based on the information you provide

Comment: Secondly, your table structure is flawed for returning a Distinct value, as pending on the querying system, some `name2` values will come first while others will come first.  You need to redesign/restructure your table so that you can produce consistent, predictable results.

Comment: The `name2` value has to be the pair of the corresponding `name1`, and `value1`.

Comment: Nevermind, I did it. I made a query, that shows the biggest values in the value1 column with their name1 values; then an other query showed the appropriate records, whose value1 is the same as in the first query.

Answer (score 0):

Access actually has the `First` function in queries, which makes it easy:

`SELECT name1, First(name2) AS name2, First(value1) AS value1 FROM TheFruitTable GROUP BY name1`

Comment: I think OP wants the record with max value1. First and Last are not reliable, [records returned by these functions will be arbitrary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/concepts/miscellaneous/first-last-functions-microsoft-access-sql).